# Powershell Understanding "continue"

Tags: powershell, continue

So in the spirit of [this](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/understanding-break-continue-return-and-exit) short but sweet tutorial I'm trying to filter out disabled user and only work on the "Enabled" users with this code. (FYI Search-ADAccount needs elevated)

```
$EXPusers = (Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired -UsersOnly)
foreach($user in $EXPusers){
    $UENB = $user.Enabled
    $UENB # Sanity Check
    if($UENB -eq "False"){
        continue
    }
    # All of this is functioning
    # disable user
    # Logoff user
    # Send email
}
```

In my lab $EXPusers just resolves to one user that is disabled or Enabled=False. So what happens is no matter what I set $UENB equal to it keeps sending mail. Seems to me that if it's "False" it should skip that iteration and not process the rest of the foreach statement and move to the next user, in this case do nothing.
What am I missing?

Comment: You should really be comparing bools to bools; i.e. `$false`, but that shouldn't affect it. Does using a label make any difference?

Comment: `$false -eq 'false'` is what you're trying to do, which is why it fails

Comment: Not sure I'm following either of you. ? $UENB is False. This is a string compare I guess so $UENB is equal to "False".

Comment: It is not a string compare, it is a comparison with a boolean, the `Enabled` property of an AD User object is a boolean, against string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it's failing is because you're comparing a [`boolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_booleans?view=powershell-7.2) (**the [`Enabled` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adaccount.enabled?view=activedirectory-management-10.0#microsoft-activedirectory-management-adaccount-enabled) of an [`ADAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adaccount?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) instance is a `bool`**) with a [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0). It's important to note that, in PowerShell a string that is **not empty** will always be `$true` and, since in your comparison the string is in the right hand side (RHS) of the comparison, PowerShell attempts type coercion as the same type of the left hand side (LHS), so the string `'false'` is converted to a *boolean* during the comparison which results being `$true`.

In [about Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2) documentation on the [**Equality operators**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#equality-operators) section we can read the following:

> The equality operator can compare objects of different types. It is important to understand that the value is on the right-hand side of the comparison can be converted to the type of the left-hand side value for comparison.

A simple demo:

```bash
[bool] 'false'     # => $true
$false -eq 'false' # => $false
'false' -eq $false # => $true
```

The last comparison results in `$true` because the boolean `$false` in the RHS is converted to string and, in PowerShell, `[string] $false` results in the literal string `false`.

In conclusion, by simply changing your `if` condition your code would work properly:

```
if($false -eq $UENB) {
    continue
}
```

The other alternative would be to use the [logical `-not` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.2):

```
if(-not $UENB) {
    continue
}
```

Comment: Ok wow this was huge for me. Thank you so much. I had seen that syntax before and just thought it was all the same.

Comment: @4evernoob it's a somewhat common mistake when learning PowerShell. Im glad the answer was helpful

Comment: huh, I figured it would coerce it into type bool; good to know!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, I'm sure you've seen this happen hundreds of time and just didn't realize it  `if ('anything') {'yesssssssss'}`.  Non-empty string always evaluates to $true, even the string 'false'

Comment: @Daniel, meant more of `$true -eq 'true' -> True`. We might just be on different pages of the same chapter haha I get you tho

Comment: @AbrahamZinala  I know, exactly, but same difference I think.    In the example I give the string is being coerced into a bool.  'anything' equals true.  Same thing is happening with $true -eq 'true' right?  or $true -eq 'false'.   I'm just saying, you've seen it just in a different way, just looks strange to see it this way.  It's like a riddle.  When is 'false' true?  When you evaluate it as a boolean in PowerShell!  :)